# R - add circles to existing time-series plot

Tags: r, zoo, lattice

I am trying to add a circle to a specific position of a `lattice` time-series `xyplot`. The plot that I have is:

```
library(zoo)
library(lattice)

t <- structure(list(date = structure(c(18172, 18177, 18182, 18187, 
                                          18192, 18202, 18212, 18217, 18222, 18237, 18257, 18267, 18287, 
                                          18322, 18327, 18332, 18337, 18342, 18347, 18357, 18362, 18367, 
                                          18372, 18377, 18382, 18392, 18402, 18407, 18412, 18432, 18437, 
                                          18447, 18452, 18457, 18462, 18467, 18477, 18482, 18497, 18502
), class = "Date"), t = c(0.22582148400414, 0.256991369867836, 
                             0.20566669217573, 0.197370049842565, 0.277943312725968, 0.409366098650766, 
                             0.485328298701375, 0.265923063666776, 0.193433942553932, 0.146475290734094, 
                             0.261228272794155, 0.287337189727423, 0.431631481918686, 0.555856286432998, 
                             0.500582779759492, 0.406387635091313, 0.270854099747563, 0.327326988684063, 
                             0.302588934307361, 0.249693446719906, 0.305548452947743, 0.397038410635602, 
                             0.439170248751657, 0.46303881959878, 0.488322795840136, 0.509185404897871, 
                             0.55092532581109, 0.551910236346757, 0.591181074665548, 0.648661902423056, 
                             0.430176528691085, 0.405420937495388, 0.437875812057808, 0.391051426411378, 
                             0.375546279814988, 0.397580900426823, 0.3510990639662, 0.196213067375209, 
                             0.188679707217845, 0.190000000000123)), row.names = c(NA, -40L
                             ), class = "data.frame")
ts <- read.zoo(t, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

xyplot(ts, col="darkgreen", lwd=2)
```

[image]

Now, I would like to add a circle centered at the 12th element of `ts`. Separately, I can plot it (sort of):

```
xyplot(ts[12][[1]] ~ ts[12], pch = 1, col = "red", cex=10)
```

[image]

But nothing happens when I attempt to update the main plot like this:

```
p <- xyplot(ts, col="darkgreen", lwd=2)

## insert additional circle
update(p, panel = function(...) {
  panel.xyplot(...)
  panel.xyplot(ndvi_ts[12], ndvi_ts[12][[1]], pch=19, cex=10, col="red")
})
```

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you a `ggplot2` approach that can be more practical than `lattice` as an option. You can use `annotate()` for the circle with `point` geom. Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplot(t,aes(x=date,y=t,group=1))+
  geom_line(color='darkgreen',size=1)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())+
  annotate(geom = 'point',x=t$date[12],y=t$t[12],size=25, shape=1, color="red")
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**1) as.layer** Define the second plot as a layer to be added to the first like this:

```
library(latticeExtra)   

p1 <- xyplot(ts, col="darkgreen", lwd=2)
p2 <- xyplot(ts[12], type = "p", col = "red", cex = 10)

p1 + as.layer(p2)
```

(continued after plot)
[image: screenshot]

**2) layer** A second way to do this is to use `layer` with a panel call rather than `as.layer` with a trellis object.  `p1` is from above.

```
library(latticeExtra)

p1 + layer(panel.points(x[12], y[12], col = "red", cex = 10))
```

**3) trellis.focus** A third way is to use `trellis.focus`:.   `p1` is from above.

```
p1
trellis.focus()
panel.points(ts[12], cex = 12, col = "red")
trellis.unfocus()
```

**4) update panel** The code in the question was close but the second `panel.xyplot` should be `panel.points`.   `p1` is from above.

```
update(p1, panel = function(...) {
  panel.xyplot(...)
  panel.points(ts[12], cex=10, col="red")
})
```

**5) autoplot.zoo** This can be done with ggplot using `autoplot.zoo`:

```
library(ggplot2)
autoplot.zoo(ts) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = time(ts)[12], y = ts[12]), pch = 1, col = "red", cex = 10)
```

**6) classic graphics**  To use classic graphics:

```
plot(ts)
points(ts[12], col = "red", cex = 10)
```